# JQuery Datatables how to handle datatable reload with angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular, datatables

I had jquery datatables which I use with angular 2, When I initialize datatable everything works fine but when I append new data to my datatable, Datatable needs to be reloaded, How can I achieve such thing?

**My JQuery Code :**

```
function InitDataTables(datatable){

    if ($('#' + datatable + '-table').length !== 0) {

        $('#' + datatable + '-table').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            responsive: true,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                { extend: 'copy', className: 'btn-sm' },
                { extend: 'csv', className: 'btn-sm' },
                { extend: 'excel', className: 'btn-sm' },
                { extend: 'pdfHtml5', className: 'btn-sm' },
                { extend: 'print', className: 'btn-sm' },
            ],
            sScrollX: "100%",
            bScrollCollapse: true
        });
    }
}
```

Data is populated from angular 2 to a normal table in html and jQuery
only init that datatable